# Suse 12 won't boot on IBM Power 7

Tags: suse, ibm-hmc

I want to install Suse Linux on IBM Power 740 Express server with HMC. 
I have downloaded Suse 12 iso file from Suse's web site. 
I burned that iso to DVD, I tried different programs to burn, 
but DVD won't boot on IBM Power 740. 
What can be the reason?
Is it burned in some specific way?

Comment: What is the ISO that you are using?  What is its name?

Comment: @jsbillings, SLE-12-SP1-Server-DVD-ppc64le-GM-DVD1.iso

Comment: What programs did you use to burn the DVD?

Comment: @jsbillings, UltraIso and NeroExpress